# Limit the amount of custom posts being shown

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, posts

Trying to limit the (custom post-type-content) being displayed on my frontpage, limited to just the newest 6 & 12 posts respectively for the 'injuries section' and 'services section'. From respective archives.

The code below works perfectly pulling in the data from each archive, but my attempt to limit the posts being shown to 6 and 12 doesn't.

Appreciate your time explaining where I'm going wrong.

```
    <?php
        // Injuries Custom Post Links 
        $args_injuries = array(
            'post_type' => array('injuries'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'limit' => '6'
        );
        // Services Custom Post Links 
        $args_services = array(
            'post_type' => array('services'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'limit' => '12'
        );
        $loop1 = new WP_Query($args_injuries);
        $loop2 = new WP_Query($args_services);
    ?>  
    <?php if ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="tile">
            <?php get_template_part('includes/front', 'page-injuries-content'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php if ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : $loop2->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="tile">
            <?php get_template_part('includes/front', 'page-services-content'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this?

Comment: I have these loops on the frontpage, pulling only 1) the image and 2) title to create a contact sheet of  teaser images to these posts, due to styling I only want to display 6 and 12 most popular of the entire list of posts.

Comment: So are you creating a page in your child theme, "index.php" this is to create the main 'blog' page?  Also... the other answer is correct, `posts_per_page` is the correct query argument.

Answer (score -1):

Use posts_per_page instead of limit. [Here](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) is 1 good article where you can see the most common arguments passed to the wp query. As I understood from your question, the only problem is limiting the posts to 6 and 12 and the rest of your code is working. In your arguments just replace 'limit' => '6' with 'posts_per_page' => '6' and that's it. Also now I've noticed you're not using [wp_reset_postdata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/), which restores the $post global to the current post in the main query. Be careful where call, this method! It should be just before the closing tag of your if statement, in other words you call it only on successful query!

```
<?php
    // Injuries Custom Post Links 
    $args_injuries = array(
        'post_type' => array('injuries'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '6'
    );
    // Services Custom Post Links 
    $args_services = array(
        'post_type' => array('services'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '12'
    );
    $loop1 = new WP_Query($args_injuries);
    $loop2 = new WP_Query($args_services);
?>  
<?php if ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="tile">
        <?php get_template_part('includes/front', 'page-injuries-content'); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_postdata(); // if query was successful reset the $post
  endif; 
?>


<?php if ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : $loop2->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="tile">
        <?php get_template_part('includes/front', 'page-services-content'); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_postdata(); // if query was successful reset the $post
  endif; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a really useful article, I'll take a good read later. Any suggestion on how I could achieve the result I'm after?